# How to fetch data and check the nos of document using MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an issue while using MongoDB with PHP. I am trying to fetch data using some condition but unable to get it. Here is my code:

```
public function adminLogin($db,$loginid,$password){
        $admin = new AdminUser();
        if(ctype_alnum($loginid)){
            $admindata=array("username"=>$loginid,"password"=>$password);
            $admincol=$db->kf_admin;
            $admindb=$admincol->find($admindata);
            print_r(iterator_to_array($admindb));exit;
            $document=$admincol->count($admindata);
            if($document > 0){
                foreach($admindb as $v){
                    $admin->adminid =htmlspecialchars($v['_id']);
                    $admin->adminname =htmlspecialchars($v['name']);
                    $admin->adminloginid =htmlspecialchars($v['username']);
                    $admin->result=1; 
                }
                print_r($admin);exit;
                return $admin;
            }else{
                $admin->result=2;
            }
        }else{
            $admin->result=2;
        }
        return $admin;
    }
```

Here I am trying to print the fetched data using find query with by matching some data but it's showing the result `Array ( )` and also can not check the no of document present inside that collection. When I am removing the `$admindata` from find() query it's rendering properly.

How can I resolve this issue?